# Scala Spark get element from HashMap

Tags: scala, hashmap, apache-spark

I have a HashMap:

[image]

And also have an array:
[image]

I take an element from that array:

[image]

And want to check if it is present in map:

[image]

However, I get false. Why?

Comment: `DenseVector` is case class?

Comment: `DenseVector` from Spark `breeze.linalg` package.

Comment: @Sergey Lagutin My code is here:https://github.com/timasjov/spark-clustering/blob/master/src/ee/ut/cs/DBSCAN.scala So feel free to test it.

Comment: It seems like `hashCode` method is not overriden for your key class. Check out my assumption.

Comment: I don't see any 'pointsMap(...)' in the code provided - note that following SO guidelines, code should be provided with the question to avoid that the change of external sources would void the question - making it unusable for anybody else. So, could you post the code in the question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

breeze.linalg.DenseVector is a 'class', so it's compared by instance equality:

```
class C(i: Int)
new C(1) == new C(1) yields false
```

if you see some code with compares two instances in scala, they work on 'case classes', because
they have a 'special equals / hashCode' method (or they implement their own equals/hashCode when working on 'normal classes').

```
case class CC(i: Int)
new CC(1) == new CC(1) yields true
```

i think you should use

```
<DenseVector instance>.values.deep == <DenseVecotor instance>.values.deep
```

- [DenseVector.values](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.0.0/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.DenseVector) to get the underlying values (Array)
- [Array.deep](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.Array@deep:IndexedSeq[Any]) to compare the array.

  Array(1, 2, 3) == Array(1, 2, 3) yields false

  Array(1, 2, 3).deep == Array(1, 2, 3).deep yields true

Example to to find values in a Map[Array[Int], String]:

```
val m = Map(Array(1, 2) -> "one", Array(1, 2) -> "two")

m.find(_._1 == Array(1, 2)) yields None
m.find(_._1.deep == Array(1, 2).deep) yields Some(...)
```

*A warning: 'find' on a Map treat the map as a sequential collection of tuples and tests every element until it finds a match, returning 'None' is there's no match. It would be basically the same as having a list (comment from @maasg)*

Comment: But HashMap doen not has `map.keys.deep` method. How can I compare then?

Comment: @bob i have add a example to find values in a map

Comment: A warning: 'find' on a Map treat the map as a sequential collection of tuples and tests every element until it finds a match, returning 'None' is there's no match. It would be basically the same as having a list.

Comment: @maasg good catch! - how can it be avoided? - i can only think of to wrap DenseVector in a class which overrides hashMap / equals?

Comment: I was going to have a look at the code, but it seems that it changed as I don't find the code referred in the question. In Spark, more often than not, having a Map does not make sense.